# How, by proving for a particular choice of $a_n$ in induction proof of AM-GM, we conclude the inequality for all $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Tags: inequality, induction

### Problematic step

> $$P(n) \implies p(n-1)$$
>   Here we assume P is true $\forall n : 0\le n \le n + 1$
>
> So,
>
> $${a_1 + a_2 + \cdots+ a_n \over n}  = \sqrt[n]{a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n}$$
>
> let $$a_n ={ a_1 + a_2 + \cdots+ a_{n-1} \over n-1}$$
>
> then we do little bit of algebraic manipulation to get the AM-GM inequality.

---

### Doubt

When taking $a_n$ specifically as  ${ a_1 + a_2 + \cdots+ a_{n-1} \over n-1}$, aren't we saying that AM-GM inequality is only true when any one term is mean of all other terms ([1]) ? aren't we suppose to prove the inequity with some general $a_n$ not a specific case.

---

counter example- [1] $$ {1+2+7\over 3} = 10/3 \ge \sqrt[3]{1*2*7} = \sqrt[3]{14}$$ 
$$7 \ne {1+2\over 2}, 2 \ne {1+7\over 2},1 \ne {7+2\over 2}$$

---

### A bit of clarification, if i sound vague

In induction proof of AM-GM by taking a specific $a_n$, how we are concluding hat it hold for all $a_n \in\mathbb{R}$

---

I am not saying that i broke maths or whatever, just want a bit of clarification.Thanks $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Have a look at: https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#proof-of-am-gm-inequality, https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Proofs_of_AM-GM.

Comment: @Macavity Ok i agree that it works with that particular choice, but what i don't understand how you can conclude it for all real numbers by proving that for a particular choice ?$\ddot \frown$

Comment: @A---B  Well if you've read the full proof, it should show it holds for all powers of two and that it holds for lesser numbers if it holds for any number. Can you find a number which is not lesser than some power of two?

Comment: @Macavity the proof i know is very similar to what @ stubborn provide in the first link, I understand how to holds for all powers for 2 but it is the second part that is causing problem to me. When we prove $P(n) \implies P(n-1)$; We take a specific choice of $a_n ={ a_1 + a_2 + \cdots+ a_{n-1} \over n-1}$, from  which we go on proving that $AM \ge GM$ then we say it holds for all choices of $a_n$. I hope i made some sense. please help me make sense of this part. $\ddot \frown$

Comment: You are not describing what the proof says.  You should read it more carefully. We assume it holds true for any $n$ variables, take a specific choice of $a_n$ to prove the case for $n-1$ variables. That is solid logic. Nothing more to explain.